# Is it possible to have Visual Studio update from SVN when I open a solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with VisualSVN and TortoiseSVN, and would like the option of being prompted to update from source control whenever I open a solution, the way SourceSafe did. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

> > to update from source control whenever I open a solution, the way SourceSafe

I think this update option is not a *SourceSafe* feature but rather it is the *Get everthing when opening a project or solution* option found in the *Visual Studio* source control options panel.

When Visual Studio connects to SourceSafe it does so using the *MS-SCCI*.

So if you use a *MS-SCCI Subversion plugin* this should also happen whenever you open a project or solution.

For example the [Agent SVN](http://www.zeusedit.com/agent/) is an MS-SCCI Subversion plugin and it should work this way.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to build an extension for VS which will use the TortoiseSVN automation API ( http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html ) and do the update when you open a solution:

Or modify existing extensions ( integrations) like AnkhSVN to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has a way to auto-prompt you, but have you tried the [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) Visual Studio Subversion Plugin? It allows you to easily update solutions, add to, etc.